# Unit prefix of zeroth power

Tags: measuring-units

Unit prefix for 10<sup>-1</sup> is deci, for 10<sup>-2</sup> centi, for 10<sup>-3</sup> milli, for 10<sup>-6</sup> micro and so on. Powers greater or equal one also have names: 10<sup>1</sup> is deca, 10<sup>2</sup> is hecto, 10<sup>3</sup> is kilo etc..

We can say, for example, *“Multiply the measurement in millimeters by 1000 and you have it in micrometers.”*

But is there a prefix (even if it's just exotic) to express the zeroth power *as an alternative* to just using *no* prefix, like in  *“Divide the measurement in millimeters by 1000 and you get it in meters.”?*

For example if we want to say it in a general way, it becomes pretty cumbersome: *“Divide the measurement in milli by 1000 and you get the prefix-less unit itself.”*

Answer (score 3):

These are called *base units*. In [SI Derived Unit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit), this Wikipedia article says

> The International System of Units (SI) specifies a set of seven base units from which all other SI units of measurement are derived.

One could say,

> Multiply the time in microseconds by 10<sup>6</sup> to obtain the base unit of seconds.

Or

> To obtain the base unit of meters, multiply the length in kilometers by 1000.

In the Wikipedia article on [SI base unit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit), note that *kilogram* is the base unit. (One might expect *gram* to be the base unit, but it is not.)

Comment: The Wikipedia article refers to this one: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit. It lists the base units as metre, kilogram, second, ampere, kelvin, mole, candela. Of the seven base units, only kilogram has a prefix. I'm editing my "base unit of grams" to use seconds instead.

Answer (score 1):

10<sup>o</sup> is 1, *[unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1).*

Thus you can just use *unit* in your sentences:

> Multiply the measurement in millimetres by 1000 and you have it in micrometres*.
>   Divide the measurement in millilitres by 1000 and you get it in litres.
>
> **Divide the measurement in *milli-* by 1000 and you get the unit itself.**

<sub>**This is slightly awkward because the more common term is* micron.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are more appropriate. But supposing you are doing this mindlessly (or rather by an automated process) have a table of prefixes indexed by power. What you are looking for is the prefix for power = 0, the string that should be prepended to the unit measure.

That prefix is called the

> **null string**

and is entered as

> **""**

in your table and this works for most programming languages.

Answer (score -1):

An exponent indicates the number of times a number is multiplied by itself: X**2 = X*X. A negative exponent indicates that the quantity is the denominator of a fraction in which the numerator is 1: X***-2 = 1/XX.

Any number raised to the power of 0 is defined to be 1: x**0 = 1.

"Deci" means 10, centi means 100 and so on, but do not actually refer to exponents.

Comment: This doesn't go anywhere near answering the question, even if it were actually clear. Hint: use `<sup></sup>` to create superscripts.